# How to properly call CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, ckeditor

In angular 2 (via [ng2-ckeditor](https://github.com/chymz/ng2-ckeditor)) I am trying to use [CKEditor-ShowProtected-Plugin](https://github.com/IGx89/CKEditor-ShowProtected-Plugin) which is not served from the ckeditor cdn.

That is why I try following:

```
import { CKEditorModule } from 'ng2-ckeditor';
declare var CKEDITOR:any;
CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal('showprotected', '../assets/ckeditor-showprotected-plugin', 'plugin.js');
```

and here is my `CKEDITOR_CONFIG`:

```
private CKEDITOR_CONFIG = {
 'extraPlugins': 'showprotected', 
  ...
}
```

however, the `CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal(..)` does not seem to be taken into account, because ckeditor is still trying to fetch the `ckeditor-showprotected-plugin` from cdn:

```
error_handler.js:54 EXCEPTION: [CKEDITOR.resourceManager.load] 
Resource name "showprotected" was not found at "https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.11/full/../assets/ckeditor-showprotected-plugin?t=G87Eplugin.js".
```

Comment: Did you ever succeed in solving this issue? And if so, could you share?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't get a chance to implement in Angular 2 ,but it in Angular 1.x do the following changes in `config.js`

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) { 

//end of configurations add following lines 
 config.extraPlugins += (config.extraPlugins.length == 0 ? '' : ',') + '<your_plugin_name>';
 config.allowedContent = true;

}
```

and add your plug-in dependencies in `ckeditor/plugins/` folder